# Flutter trying to connect to device returns java.io.IOException

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

Creating a new connection to a device using Flutter_blue_serial gives the following error:

```
PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
          at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:952)
          at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:966)
          at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:522)
at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:57)
at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:64)
at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler.lambda$onMethodCall$4$io-github-edufolly-flutterbluetoothserial-FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler(FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.java:1007)
at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.r
```

I have tried connecting to different bluetooth devices with same result

Here is the block of code from which the error results:

```
      List<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = await fbs.getBondedDevices();
      for(BluetoothDevice device in bondedDevices.where((x)=>x.address == device.device.address)){
        BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address).then(
        (connection){
          print('connected');
          _connection =connection;
        }
      ).catchError((onError)=>{
        print("caughtError:"),
        print(onError)
      });
      }
```

I tried looking for a solution but cannot find any, another library that supports non-ble devices would also be useful.

Comment: In my case the problem was in flutter_bluetooth_serial library , calling the .toAddressFunction with address only was connecting on  a default uuid. Based on this comment here [link](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/issues/154#issuecomment-1158520603) i changed the method as described and it fixed the problem

Comment: Hey, great that you were able to find the problem and fix it! Feel free to [answer] your own question and accept it. This helps future readers to find the solution quicker :)